# Не сохраняется файл flask

Tags: python, html, post, flask, get

Я хочу сделать небольшой домашний сервер для сохранения и скачивания файлов, написал вот такой код

```
from flask import *
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
import os


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = "/files"

@app.route("/")
def send_home():
    return render_template("home.html")


@app.route("/find")
def send_find():
    return render_template("changefile.html")


@app.route('/download', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def reg_run():
    a = request.form['filename']
    print("files/" + a)
    return send_from_directory("files/", a, as_attachment=True)


@app.route("/save")
def send():
    return render_template("save.html")


@app.route('/save_file', methods=['POST'])
def send1():
    if request.method == 'POST': 
        f = request.files['filename'] 
        f.save(f.filename) 
        print(f.filename)
    return redirect("/")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run("0.0.0.0", port="80", debug=True)
```

А вот так выглядит код html страницы с сохранением файла на сервер

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>save</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/save_file">
            <input type="file" name="filename">
            <button type="submit" value="Upload">save</button>
        </form>
        <a href="/find">Download</a><br>
        <a href="/save">Save</a><br>
        <a href="/">Home</a><br>
    </body>
    </html>
```

После того, как я перехожу на адрес 127.0.0.1/save и выбираю любой файл, когда я нажимаю "Сохранить" я получаю редирект на 127.0.0.1, все проходит без ошибок, но в директории /files сервера ничего не появляется. Вывод в консоль на сервере такой:

```
192.168.0.87 - - [31/Oct/2023 08:35:50] "GET /save HTTP/1.1" 200 -
test.py
192.168.0.87 - - [31/Oct/2023 08:36:26] "POST /save_file HTTP/1.1" 302 -
192.168.0.87 - - [31/Oct/2023 08:36:26] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

После поиска значения статус кода 302 в интеренте я нашел что этот статус код означает

> "Запрошенный документ временно доступен по другому URI, указанному в
> заголовке в поле Location"

Я не очень понимаю сто это значит, пожалуйста помогите! (Если что-то забыл указать напишите это в комментарии к вопросу)

Comment: У вас при `f.save(f.filename)` файл сохраняется в корневую директорию. Если вы хотите сохранять в файл в `UPLOAD_FOLDER` нужно добавить ее к пути сохранения файла - например так `f.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], f.filename))`. При этом  значение `UPLOAD_FOLDER` нужно изменить с `files` вместо `/files`.

Comment: Я это понимаю и думал что проблема в этом, поэтому временно сделал сохранение файлов в корневую директорию проекта, но это не помогает файл не сохраняется не так не так впринципе никуда

Comment: посмотри от какого пользователя запускается фласк, и выдай ему права на папку, куда хочешь сохранять файлы. Сохранять в корень, даже для тестов - дурной тон.

Comment: У меня виндовс, запускаю от имени администратора, права на папку у поьзователя есть 100%. И на моем втором пк на линукс то же самое. На хостинге тоже ничего не работает